# How do I submit an additional commit after submitting previous commit to Gerrit?

Tags: git, gerrit

I'm attempting to submit an additional (unrelated) commit after submitting a previous commit to Gerrit. I've created the previous and the current commit on two separate branches. Here is an example of the workflow:

1. `git checkout -b <branch-1>`
2. `git add folder1/*`
3. `git commit -m "Added folder1."`
4. `git review`

It is submitted to Gerrit and it outputs information including the link to the review. Afterwards, I go to work on another (again, unrelated) change:

5. `git checkout -b <branch-2>`
6. `git add folder2/*`
7. `git commit -m "Added folder2."`
8. `git review`

It is at this point that I encounter the following:

```
You are about to submit multiple commits. This is expected if you are
submitting a commit that is dependent on one or more in-review
commits. Otherwise you should consider squashing your changes into one
commit before submitting.

The outstanding commits are:
373ea8b (HEAD -> branch-2) Added folder2.
e626f4c (branch-1) Added folder1.

Do you really want to submit the above commits?
Type 'yes' to confirm, other to cancel: n
Aborting.
```

How do I avoid this conflict?

Comment: By "submitted", do you mean "pushed"? Gerrit's "submit" is to merge the commit into the target branch after review. You can see the "Submit" button on the change page. If the first is not submitted yet, and if the second is dependent on the first, then the second can't be submitted. So it warns when `git review`. You could either answer "yes", or git-review the first, submit it and then git-review the second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you did the second commit based on the first one:

```
A             <= origin/branch
 \ 
  \-- B       <= branch-1
       \
        \-- C <= branch-2
```

To work on unrelated branch you should work "in parallel" with independent commits like these:

```
  /-- B <= branch-1
 /
A       <= origin/branch
 \
  \-- C <= branch-2
```

First commit:

```
git checkout -b <branch-1> origin/<branch>
git add folder1/*
git commit -m "Added folder1."
git review
```

Second commit:

```
git checkout -b <branch-2> origin/<branch>
git add folder2/*
git commit -m "Added folder2."
git review
```